# Size of the deck transformation group

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

If $p\colon Y\to X$ is a $k$-fold covering map, and $Y$ is path-connected, what is the size of Deck($p$), the deck transformation group?

I was attempting to prove that the answer is $\leq k$, but thought of an example where I think it is $k!$, so my question is - where have I gone wrong?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejLk0.png]

*image borrowed from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872417/244596).*

In particular it is this example from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, the three-fold cover of the figure 8 graph pictured above. Could we not use any different combination of $a$ or $b$ to permute the vertices (labeled $v_1,v_2,v_3$ from left-to-right) into any order? i.e. can the deck group be isomorphic to $S_3$ with elements:

1. $e$
2. $a$ - fixes $v_1$, switches $v_2$ and $v_3$
3. $b$ - fixes $v_3$, switches $v_1$ and $v_2$
4. $bab$ - fixes $v_2$, switches $v_1$ and $v_3$
5. $ab$ - $v_1\mapsto v_2$, $v_2\mapsto v_3$, $v_3\mapsto v_1$
6. $ba$ - $v_1\mapsto v_3$, $v_2\mapsto v_1$, $v_3\mapsto v_2$

I realize I am wrong, but would like to know why to help my understanding of deck groups, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that any $f\in\text{Deck}(p)$ fixes some $x\in Y$ if and only if $f=id_Y$. Suppose that the size of $\text{Deck}(p)$ is greater than $k$. Then by the pigeonhole principle, there are $\tau,\sigma\in\text{Deck}(p)\setminus id_Y$ such that $\tau({V_1})=\sigma({V_1})=V_i$, without loss of generality, where $V_1,V_i,\,i\leq k$ are disjoint subsets of $Y$ that are mapped homeomorphically onto $X$ by $p$, as in the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Formal_definition) of covering spaces.

We have that for all $x\in V_1$, $p\circ\tau(x)=p(x)$, and $p\circ\sigma(x)=p(x)$, and given that $p|_{V_i}$ is a homeomorphism, we must have $\tau(x)=\sigma(x)$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

The Deck transformation group acts freely on $Y$ and preserves the fibers so its cardinal is inferior to the cardinal of the fiber

Comment: sorry, what does it mean for a group to act freely on a topological space? Also, as an example, how does this relate to my example above (where do i fail to preserve fibers)?

Comment: it means it does not fix a point, f(x)=x i.e f is the identity

Comment: So in my example, numbers 2, 3, 4 are incorrect as they fix vertices? Is there any particular reason why this property means the cardinal is lower (it isn't obvious to me that it follows), for example I can think of [5 ways of permuting 4 vertices without fixed points](http://i.imgur.com/AdBNobZ.jpg)